# change <li> style by click

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am using Angular CLI. Actually, I have a menu list. And I would like to change the background color of `<li>` when I click on it.
I send `id` to  function`changeColor()`. But the problem is I am getting menuButton as null. Please help me to do so.

**.html**

```
<ul>
   <li id="menu_btn" (click)="changeColor()" >

   </li>
   <li id="menu_btn" (click)="changeColor()"> 

   </li>
<ul>
```

**.ts:**

```
changeColor() {
    let menuButton = document.getElementById("menu_btn"); 
    menuButton.style.backgroundColor = '#816587';
  }
```

Comment: You should not do it like this. Avoid DOM manipulation in controller. It's not going to work well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more angular way to do this is define your menu list in an array

```
// component.ts
menuList = [
    {
        name: 'Option 1',
        isSelected: false
    },
    {
        name: 'Option 2',
        isSelected: false
    }
];
```

Then use an ngFor to render the list and use ngClass + each menu items `isSelected` flag to toggle a `selected` class.

```
// component.html
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuList" (click)="changeColor(menuItem)"
        [ngClass]="{'selected': menuItem.isSelected}">
        {{menuItem.name}}
    </li>
</ul>

// component.css
.selected{
    background-color: #816587;
}
```

Now have your changeColor method handle the toggling of the isSelected flag

```
changeColor(menuItem){
    // toggle off all selected menu items
    this.menuList.forEach(item => {
        if(item.isSelected){
            item.isSelected = false;
        }
    });
    // select clicked menu item
    menuItem.isSelected = true;
}
```

This way angular is handling all of the DOM manipulation. Here is plnkr demonstrating this functionality (https://plnkr.co/edit/NEnzKZ84M85mErYGLE1Y?p=preview)

Comment: and what about if my menu items are font awesome icons?

Comment: @tatamingi you can add the icon class to each array item `{icon: 'fa-arrow-up', isSelected: false}`. and in your html use the icon property within ngClass. `<i class="fa" [ngClass]="menuItem.icon"></i>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngStyle to do this:

```
<li id="menu_btn" (click)="myStyle = {'background-color': #816587}" [ngStyle]="myStyle">
```

Comment: I need click block and change color and click another block change color but the previous one return its color